# Mermaid.js issues with box width cutting text

Tags: javascript, flask, styling, mermaid

I'm looking to integrate mermaid.js into my flask application but I am encountering a strange error.

The text within boxes get's cut short by about 5-10 pixels

The following code creates this output:

```
<div class="mermaid">
    %%{init: {
        'theme': 'forest', 
        "flowchart" : { "curve" : "basis" } 
    } }%%
    graph LR
        id1[This is the text in the box]
</div>
```

[image]

As you see the two last letters are cropped, this happens for all boxes.

Any Idea as to how I should remidy this?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it by reducing the font-size to 90%